# Is it possible .zshrc is not available in ~?

Tags: macos, zsh

I can’t find the file `.zshrc` in my user home folder, is it possible it doesn’t exist and I have to create it as a new file? I use zsh as default shell on macOS 11.2.3

Comment: It doe s not exist by default a nd you have to create it did it work before as you can configure zsh to re d the rc file from a mother directory

Comment: Usually, files don't spring into existence by themselves. If you want to make use of this file, you have to create it using a text editor.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no `.zshrc` file in your home dir unless you create one, which you can do with a plain text editor of your choice. Do make sure that you save the file as plain text (not rich text) and that do *not* add an extension like `.txt` to it.